# Is downloading Windows ISOs from TechBench downloaders safe?

Tags: windows, web-browser, vulnerability

## How safe are TechBench downloaders?

Is it safe to download an iso from TechBench downloading service for example:

https://tb.rg-adguard.net/public.php

I have no idea how it works but it *supposedly* downloads the ISO directly from Microsoft servers.

Chrome says the download for Windows 7 Ultimate is coming from

https://software-download.microsoft.com/pr/Win7_Ult_SP1_English_x64.iso?t=fa97b958-6996-4845-bdc4-42239af90448&e=1518109568&h=2803582e3572c264fb2da3854d6cc239

<sup>(I think the link above is only good for 24 for those trying to test it, it may have already expired but you can generate a new one using the website)</sup>

> Note: These are hidden downloads, no longer "officially" hosted by
> microsoft (they are still on MS servers but hidden). Originally these were on Digital River (anybody remember that?), now they are on
> techbench but hidden.

<sup>I'm not debating the legality of this. I'm just asking if the actual process of doing this is safe and if you feel like explaining how it works you can.</sup>

Comment: What kind of assurance you need when it clearly says it's downloaded from microsoft? Microsoft allows to download their Windows 10 ISOs but you need to have Linux browser, then it shows downloads, otherwise you need license.

Comment: @Aria Not windows 10. All versions of Windows 7, 8, insider previews, etc... Basically everything that is hosted but hidden on techbench

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have essentially answered your own question. It appears that TechBench is simply providing an interface to download these "hidden" files from Microsoft's servers.

Given that Google Chrome says you're downloading from `https://software-download.microsoft.com/`, you're getting the file straight from Microsoft over a secure connection. So yes, it's safe.

Comment: Seemed obvious but I've been surprised by other vulnerabilities and exploits so it just helps you sleep easy to hear what the professionals have to say. Thanks!